# Is it possible to disrupt the communication between two parties without a TCP RST attack?

Tags: python, tcp, udp, scapy, flooding

I was wondering if it was possible to disrupt the communication between two parties by sending a large amount of packets with a spoofed source address (HOST A) so that the targeted address (HOST B) would stop responding to the spoofed source address (HOST A).

I'm already aware of TCP RST attacks, but that's not what I'm looking for: I'd like the sequence number, window size, and the likes not to be a necessary acknowledgement for the attack.

What I'm trying to disrupt is an HTTP communication. I'm using Scapy, by the way.

Comment: You need to know the source and destination ports.

Comment: The sequence number also has to be valid. See the description of the "Segment Arrives" processing in RFC 793.

Comment: I assume the way to go is UDP floods then.

Comment: That will be a more general DOS attack.